# Specialization in rust

Tags: rust, traits, implements

Rust's specialization works very poorly with related types, and I would like to know alternatives

Trait:

```
pub trait IntoConfig<T, U>
    where T: AsRef<[u8]> + AsRef<Path>,
          U: IntoIterator<Item=T>,
          <Self as IntoConfig<T, U>>::Matches: AsRef<[u8]>,
          <Self as IntoConfig<T, U>>::Path: AsRef<Path>
{
    type Path;
    type Matches;
    type Error;
    fn to_config(self) -> Result<Config<Self::Path, Self::Matches>, Self::Error>;
}
```

I needed to make optimized implementations for my config creator trait. But specialization in the rust
works very poorly with associated types.

my realisation:

```
auto trait NonOptConfGen {}
impl<T> ! NonOptConfGen for &[T] {}
```

```
impl<T, U> IntoConfig<T, U> for U
    where T: AsRef<[u8]> + AsRef<Path> + AsRef<str>,
          U: IntoIterator<Item=T>,
          Self: NonOptConfGen 
{
    type Path = T;
    type Matches = String;
    type Error = &'static str;

    fn to_config(self) -> Result<Config<Self::Path, Self::Matches>, Self::Error> {
  ...
    }

}
```

```
impl<'a, T> IntoConfig<&'a T, &'a [T]> for &'a [T]
    where T: AsRef<[u8]> + AsRef<Path> + AsRef<str>,

{
    type Path = &'a T;
    type Matches = &'a str;
    type Error = &'static str;

    fn to_config(self) -> Result<Config<Self::Path, Self::Matches>, Self::Error> {
     ...
    }
}
```

but when I tried to introduce the second level of Specialization,everything
became much compliacated due to the lack of  "negative bound" in the language.

My decision:

```
auto trait NonOptConfGenT1 {}
auto trait NonOptConfGen {}
impl<T> ! NonOptConfGen for &[T] {}
impl<T: Copy> ! NonOptConfGenT1 for &[T] {}
```

and

```
impl<T, U> IntoConfig<T, U> for U
    where T: AsRef<[u8]> + AsRef<Path> + AsRef<str>,
          U: IntoIterator<Item=T>,
          Self: NonOptConfGen + NonOptConfGenT1
```

,

```
impl<'a, T> IntoConfig<&'a T, &'a [T]> for &'a [T]
    where T: AsRef<[u8]> + AsRef<Path> + AsRef<str>,
          Self: NonOptConfGenT1
```

As for me , my decision is suboptimal. What else can be done?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you find suboptimal with that solution?

Comment: side note: you should define constraints on associated types in your trait by doing `type Path: AsRef<Path>` instead of `where <Self as _>::Path: AsRef<Path>`

Comment: You should try and add constraints as locally as possible. For instance leave trait declarations free of constraints, and add the constraints either at the methods within the `impl` block that need them, or less commonly at the `impl` level. Maybe you don't need an auto trait if you only intend to apply the trait where needed to a couple specific things.

Comment: kmdreko, thank you,  I didn't know about this syntax

Comment: As a result, I solved the problem without using specialization or something like that. I changed the approach to implementation, I changed the input arguments and their analysis in the function

Comment: Todd, thank you.  I understand what you were saying